# Do small dogs live longer than large dogs?

Tags: zoology, life-expectancy, dogs

I thought small dogs lived longer than large dogs, then I stumbled on this [answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/5702/417) about heart beats and longevity.

In the following table:

[image]

Large dogs are said to live longer than small dogs. Which is contrary to some beliefs, like in this [article](http://www.pethealthnetwork.com/dog-health/dog-checkups-preventive-care/do-small-dogs-live-longer).

So who is right?

Comment: Note that the weight listed for "large dogs" is 8kg (17.6 lbs), which most people would still call small, or medium at best. The only major breed that is regularly 2kg ("small") is Chihuahua, I believe.

Comment: yeah as geobits points out, this is a really bad chart were dogs are concerned, because anything bigger then a corgi seems to be considered a large dog here, so depending on what other people view to be small vs large its hard to tell by this. though i believe dogs like golden retrievers, labs, German shepherds all have around a 15-17 year life expectancy.

Comment: It's not much better for horses. 1200kg is far more than the average horse's weight. Even large draft horses very seldomly top 1000kg.

Comment: The heart rate for a large whale looks too high.

Comment: Same goes for humans. They use 90kg as the average weight, but this seems unlikely in most of the world...

Comment: For that matter, why are these weights listed in GRAMS? Makes it feel like this table was pulled from some halfassed game data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, small dog breeds tend to live longer than larger breeds.

- [Longevity of British breeds of dog and its relationships with sex, size, cardiovascular variables and disease:](http://europepmc.org/abstract/MED/10619607)

> smaller dogs had longer lifespans.

- [Statistical analysis regarding the effects of height and weight on life span of the domestic dog:](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034528806001226)

> A negative correlation was observed between height and longevity (r = −0.603, p < 0.05), and between weight and longevity (r = −0.679, p < 0.05). Weight was the significant predictor of life span (p < 0.001), revealing that breeds smaller by weight generally live longer than heavier breeds.

- [Do large dogs die young?](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jez.b.21116/abstract)

> In most animal taxa, longevity increases with body size across species, as predicted by the oxidative stress theory of aging. In contrast, in within-species comparisons of mammals and especially domestic dogs (e.g. Patronek et al., '97; Michell, '99; Egenvall et al., 2000; Speakman et al., 2003), longevity decreases with body size.